# Offline storage - db sync

Tags: html, local-storage, offline-mode, app-offline.htm

My question is:

How can a make my Web app to store local data if not connected to internet and once the connection is available sync them with server.

What is best solution to do this.

My app is cakephp / mysql, I want to beable to store data, even if connection is down. I could use Sqlite too. I need to know if is possible to make this sync. So, No connection, use sqlite, connection ready, sync it with server.

Comment: Couchdb has this functionality too!

Comment: I doesn't look like? Any example?

Comment: as stated in the [couchdb docs](http://couchdb.apache.org/docs/overview.html) "The CouchDB document storage, view and security models are designed to work together to make true bi-directional replication efficient and reliable. Both documents and designs can replicate, allowing full database applications (including application design, logic and data) to be replicated to laptops for offline use, or replicated to servers in remote offices where slow or unreliable connections make sharing data difficult."

Comment: Make it as answer so I can mark it, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as stated in the [couchdb](http://couchdb.apache.org/docs/overview.html) docs "The CouchDB document storage, view and security models are designed to work together to make true bi-directional replication efficient and reliable. Both documents and designs can replicate, allowing full database applications (including application design, logic and data) to be replicated to laptops for offline use, or replicated to servers in remote offices where slow or unreliable connections make sharing data difficult."